# Search on 2 properties in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

```golang
query := bson.M{
    "nombre": bson.M{"$regex": `(?i)` + search}, // me va a buscar los nombres que contengan search
}
```

I had this code to do a search in my DB where I have name and surname. I want this query to be valid for all those instances in which the name contains the search string, but I would also like to add the search by last name, since if something other than the name appeared in search, the query would be executed incorrectly. How could I implement such a query to be able to filter by first and last name?

Comment: please add the schema `struct` in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know if user will pass only first name or first name with last name

```golang
search := "Carlos M"
s := strings.Split(search, " ")
s := append(s, "") // incase name is only supplied then empty string will be used for surname
query := bson.M{
    "nombre": bson.M{"$regex": `(?i)` + s[0]},
    "apellido": bson.M{"$regex": `(?i)` + s[1]},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex

```
query := bson.M{
        "nombre": bson.M{"$regex": `\s`+surname+`\b`},
    }
```

\s matches any whitespace character

\b assert ending

Comment: Maybe my explain was wrong, I have a string (search), with for example, "Carlos M".
I just want to find  the tuples with :   {name: "Carlos", surname: "Moreno"}, {name: "Carlos", surname: "Mahrez"}.